# Why the fourth tab is not displaying any data but the first three does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have 4 different tabs created in my html. I am able to switch between all 4 tabs just fine, but for some reason tab 4 doesn't display its associated content. I am not sure why the first three tabs are working fine and I am able to see their data, but not for tab 4.

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/2t50egkn/3/

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs-list">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3<a/></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4<a/></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
      <div id="">
        <strong>TAB 1:</strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum quod doloribus quaerat ab porro at necessitatibus alias molestiae dolores facere rem debitis dolorum inventore, vel error animi deleniti ipsum, labore.
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <div id="">
        <strong>TAB 2:</strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum quod doloribus quaerat ab porro at necessitatibus alias molestiae dolores facere rem debitis dolorum inventore, vel error animi deleniti ipsum, labore.
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <div id="">
        <strong>TAB 3:</strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum quod doloribus quaerat ab porro at necessitatibus alias molestiae dolores facere rem debitis dolorum inventore, vel error animi deleniti ipsum, labore.
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab">
   <div id="">
        <strong>TAB 4:</strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum quod doloribus quaerat ab porro at necessitatibus alias molestiae dolores facere rem debitis dolorum inventore, vel error animi deleniti ipsum, labore.
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tabs-list li a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(".tabs-list li").click(function(){
      var tabid = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
      $(".tabs-list li,.tabs div.tab").removeClass("active");
      $(".tab").hide();
      $(tabid).show();
      $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: First step, check the opening and closing of your "a" tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your opening/closing "a" tags are not valid

```
  <ul class="tabs-list">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3<a/></li> <-- needs to be </a>
      <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4<a/></li> <-- ditto!
  </ul>
```

ie.

```
  <ul class="tabs-list">
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li> 
  </ul>
```

Comment: Dang, got it a few seconds before I did! This is it.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest little things that are staring us in the face, but we just can see them!

Comment: oh Wow, I can't believe I didn't noticed that. Thank you so much for making me realized that.

Comment: @Shaun - happens to the best of us ...... (often several times a day!) :)

Answer (score 0):

Anchor closing tag for tab 3 and tab 4 are incorrect. Replace with the below lines.

```
 <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
```